# Type of Amazon xml response breaks php xsl

Tags: xslt, amazon-web-services

Since Amazon shut off it's xslt support, I wanted to move it to my own server using php5's xsl. My output needs to be in a text format for my JS to process it for a web page. My problem is Amazon's xml response (very abbreviated) looks like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <ItemLookupResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
       /............./
    </ItemLookupResponse>
```

My problem is that my xsl stylesheet works fine as long as I remove the xmlns="http://...". What is needed in a xsl style to have it bypass or just ignore that ?
All the nodes I need are well inside that outer one.

Here is the xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name="CallBack" select="'amzJSONCallback'"/>
<xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="$CallBack"/>
  <xsl:text>( { "Item" : </xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:text> } ) </xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="OperationRequest"></xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="Request"></xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Items">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Item"/>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Item">
  <xsl:text> {</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>"title":"</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="ItemAttributes/Title"/><xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>"author":"</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="ItemAttributes/Author"/><xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>"pubbdate":"</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="ItemAttributes/PublicationDate"/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>} </xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Any chance you can post your XSLT, or a minimal example of it that recreates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably learn how XML namespaces work. In a nutshell, you have to define a namespace prefix in your XSL file like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ... xmlns:awse="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
```

Then, you have to use qualified names to match and select elements under that namespace:

```
<xsl:template match="awse:ItemLookupResponse">
```

(With XSLT 2.0, you can define a default namespace. But since you're using PHP, you're probably limited to XSLT 1.0.)

Comment: I am familiar with how namespaces work, but I know I'm no expert. I think that's what Amazon stopped supporting. They will deliver the xml response, but it's now completely up to the users to convert the xml to usable content. They no longer support anything that supports xlst.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like nwellnhof is correct. I was using the wrong namespace in my testing. All I did was add:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ... xmlns:aws="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01">
```

Then the elements look like

```
<xsl:template match="aws:ItemLookupResponse">
```

Now the conversion works perfectly. I don't know why it didn't work the first time I tried it.